# python list dependency based on other value in same list

Tags: python

I am struggling to figure how to make dependency b/w values in python list.

Basically I have a list like below. from the below list ,i can pass a input value as **TABLE_VIEW**
based on the input value , i want to generate dependency list in a order.

**INPUT**

```
    1.EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG,TARGET_TABLE
    2.SQ_TABLE_NAME,EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG
    3.TABLE_VIEW,SQ_TABLE_NAME
    4.EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG,LKP_NEW_TABLE_3
    5.SQ_TABLE_NAME,LKP_NEW_TABLE_1
    6.EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG,LKP_NEW_TABLE_2
    7.LKP_NEW_TABLE_1,TARGET_TABLE
```

For example 3rd one value is **TABLE_VIEW,SQ_TABLE_NAME**, so here based on 2nd value i.e SQ_TABLE_NAME I want to find out next dependency so in this case

SQ_TABLE_NAME,EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG
SQ_TABLE_NAME,LKP_NEW_TABLE_1

again from above two , take the 2nd value and again make dependency.

EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG,LKP_NEW_TABLE_3
EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG,LKP_NEW_TABLE_2
EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG,TARGET_TABLE
LKP_NEW_TABLE_1,TARGET_TABLE

I may have up to 50 list like this, but wanted to put them in dependency order based on 2nd value.

**OUTPUT:**

```
1.TABLE_VIEW,SQ_TABLE_NAME
2.SQ_TABLE_NAME,EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG
3.SQ_TABLE_NAME,LKP_NEW_TABLE_1
4.EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG,LKP_NEW_TABLE_3
5.EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG,LKP_NEW_TABLE_2
6.EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG,TARGET_TABLE
7.LKP_NEW_TABLE_1,TARGET_TABLE
```

I have tried writing static query by taking multiple list variable and deleted already processed one original list, but I many never know when all values ends up. Can you please share some thoughts how to implement this dynamically?

```
sq_order_dependency=[]

for sq_dep in job_dependent_details:
    if 'SQ' in sq_dep.split(',')[0] :
        sq_order_dependency.append(sq_dep)
        job_dependent_details.remove(sq_dep)
        
sq_order_dependency1=[]

for sq_depenent_order in sq_order_dependency:
    next_dependency=sq_depenent_order.split(',')[1]
    #print(next_dependency)
    for job_dependent_details_list in job_dependent_details:
        if next_dependency in job_dependent_details_list.split(','[0]):
            #print(job_dependent_details_list)
            sq_order_dependency.append(job_dependent_details_list)


for i in sq_order_dependency:
   job_dependent_details.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well according to your examples and data there should be no duplicates so it should work i think.
main function is based on recursive call (something like dfs)
this works only for directed edges and without self-node edge.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a=['EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG, TARGET_TABLE'
,'SQ_TABLE_NAME, EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG'
,'TABLE_VIEW, SQ_TABLE_NAME'
,'EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG, LKP_NEW_TABLE_3'
,'SQ_TABLE_NAME, LKP_NEW_TABLE_1'
,'EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG, LKP_NEW_TABLE_2'
,'LKP_NEW_TABLE_1, TARGET_TABLE']
a = [i.replace(" ",'') for i in a]
sql_data = [tuple(i.split(',')) for i in a]

class CustomGraphDependency:
    #desired for question
    def __init__(self,data:list):
        self.graph = defaultdict(set)  # no self edge
        self.add_dependency(data)
        self.count = 1
    def add_dependency(self,data:list):
        for node1,node2 in data: #directed edge only
            self.graph[node1].add(node2)

    def dependency_finder_with_count(self,node: str, sq_order_dependency: list, flag: list):
        # (e.x 1.TABLE_VIEW,SQ_TABLE_NAME )
        flag.append(node)
        for item in self.graph[node]:
            sq_order_dependency.append((self.count,node,item))
            if item not in flag:
                self.count+=1
                self.dependency_finder_with_count(item, sq_order_dependency, flag)

        return sorted(sq_order_dependency,key=lambda x: x[0])

obj_test = CustomGraphDependency(sql_data).dependency_finder_with_count('TABLE_VIEW', [], [])
for i in obj_test:
    print(i)
'''
(1, 'TABLE_VIEW', 'SQ_TABLE_NAME')
(2, 'SQ_TABLE_NAME', 'EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG')
(3, 'EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG', 'LKP_NEW_TABLE_3')
(4, 'EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG', 'TARGET_TABLE')
(5, 'EXP_TABLE_NAME_STG', 'LKP_NEW_TABLE_2')
(6, 'SQ_TABLE_NAME', 'LKP_NEW_TABLE_1')
(7, 'LKP_NEW_TABLE_1', 'TARGET_TABLE')
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow a different approach, i.e. build a tree-like structure of dependency pairs, and then print out the tree.

In the following code I defined a simple `Dep` class and chose a depth first traversal for showing the tree, both for readability; and since we meet the dependencies in an unspecified order, I used a helper dictionary. Oh, and I abbreviated the table names out of laziness :)

```
class Dep():
    def __init__(self, name, children = None):
        self.name = name
        if children:
            self.children = [children]
        else:
            self.children = []
    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)
    def show(self, level=0):
        for c in self.children:
            print ('\t'*level, self.name, c.name)
            c.show(level+1)

def show_dependencies(deps):
    out = {}
    root = deps[0][0]
    for d in y:
        pname, cname = d
        if cname in out:
            c = out[cname]
        else:
            c = Dep(cname)
            out[cname] = c
        if pname in out:
            out[pname].add_child(c)
        else:
            out[pname] = Dep(pname, c)
        if root == cname:
            root = pname
    out[root].show()

>>> show_dependencies([('EXP','TARGET'),('SQ','EXP'),('TABLE','SQ'),('EXP','LKP3'),('SQ','LKP1'),('EXP','LKP2'),('LKP1','TARGET')])
 TABLE SQ
     SQ EXP
         EXP TARGET
         EXP LKP3
         EXP LKP2
     SQ LKP1
         LKP1 TARGET
```